# Expanding item in QTreeView in PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

I'm trying to learn PyQt and follow its documentation. So I have this simple code which is supposed to expand a selected item in a `QteeView.` Documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#expand says that `expand()` method "Expands the model item specified by the index." but it does not work. I also tried `setExpand()` and `expandAll()` both don't work neither.

**How should I read this documentation to make my code do what it is supposed to do?**

This exercise is the first step to help me expand all folders to the very deepest one since `expandAll()` expands only the first level of the tree.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class GUI(QWidget):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(GUI, self).__init__(parent)

       path = "C:/TEMP"
       self.model = QFileSystemModel()
       self.model.setRootPath(path)

       self.view = QTreeView()
       self.view.setModel(self.model)
       self.view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(path))

       self.but_1 = QPushButton(self)
       self.but_1.setText("BUT 1")

       self.but_2 = QPushButton(self)
       self.but_2.setText("BUT 2")

       self.V_layout = QVBoxLayout()
       self.V_layout.addWidget(self.view)

       self.V_layout.addWidget(self.but_1)
       self.V_layout.addWidget(self.but_2)
       self.setLayout(self.V_layout)

       index_1 = self.model.index("C:/TEMP")
       index_2 = self.model.index("C:/TEMP/bbbbb")

       self.but_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.aaa(index_1))
       self.but_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.aaa(index_2))

       self.view.expandAll()

   def aaa(self, index):
       self.view.expand(index)
       self.view.setExpanded(index, True)
       print(index)
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   g = GUI()
   g.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You will certainly *not* want to expand the whole tree of a file system model. It could take minutes, and even go virtually indefinitely (until memory allows) in certain cases. Besides, indexes are "volatile", especially for dynamic models such as this, computing the index right at startup and trying to expand it *later* will most certainly fail, since the QFileSystemModel loads its contents asynchronously. Instead, use the lambda with the path, and compute the index when actually needed.

Comment: What is the use-case for expanding all the folders? Surely it would be much more effective to simply set the root index to the relevant folder?

Comment: User will select 2 folders and compare their content for duplicates. Finally, I want to display all subfolders expanded with all duplicate files selected and marked with red. I can make Windows Explorer display all files in the drive by typing `*.*` in the search box and nobody is surprised that it takes ages to display everything. My program will be as just good as WE is. But here I'm actually asking why if I do what Qt documentation says it does not work. How should I read this documentation? Do I miss something reading that expand() method "Expands the model item specified by the index."?

Comment: @musicamante Ideally I will use `QPersistentModelIndex` to avoid the problem you describe but my problem is much simpler at the moment which is that I'm not able to implement a simple method baseing only on Documentation and without coping all snippets from Stack Overflow. I'm really starting to doubt in my mental abilities since I'm struggling with this Qt thing for months now and reading documentation never worked.

Comment: @Zwornik using a persistent index won't change much, especially considering that the parent of the index might be invalidated for some reason (thus invalidating the persistent index along with it). As said, QFileSystemModel works *asynchronously* using both its internal cache and the system cache, and if a sub-level path is given for an index at startup there's no guarantee that the same index will still be valid at a later moment. You **must** call `index()` dynamically at each request in order to get a valid index for the view.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation musicamante. I understand that the index may become invalid because I delete a file, but will that make the index invalid only if that file or other files following deled one will also get invalid indexes, or indexes will get invalid randomly? What kind of events make them invalid, except deletion?

Comment: @Zwornik I think that because of the models asynchronous nature, every time you expand a new branch of the tree you could potentially be invalidating every previously calculated index in the model.

Comment: The issue with invalid indexes is a bit of a red herring. The real problem is that (as stated in the Qt docs) the expand methods don't fetch more data. You should therefore use a [QDirIterator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html) to iterate recursively over the subdirectories and explictly expand each one using an index obtained *directly from the directory path*. Doing it that way will only require about four lines of code if you use the correct filters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the index in the lambda function, try passing the path instead, and then getting the index just before calling expand.  I am not entirely sure why, but doing it this way worked fine for me.

For example:

```
       path_1 = "C:/TEMP"
       path_2 = "C:/TEMP/bbbbb"

       self.but_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.aaa(path_1))
       self.but_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.aaa(path_2))

   def aaa(self, path):
       index = self.model.index(path)
       self.view.expand(index)
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander, that works. Unfortunately, I am too new to this website to give a point to your answer. May I ask you why when I do it like that 
        `path = "C:/TEMP/bbbbb"
        index = self.model.index(path)
         self.view.expandAll()
         def aaa(self, path, index):
        self.view.expand(index)`
        it does expand only folder `bbbbb` when I even didn't call function `aaa`? I would expect `expandAll()` to expand the top level of all folders at least, not just one?

Comment: I think expandAll, literally expands all branches. not just the top level. And based on the notes in the documentation calling this method does not fetch more data.  So unless  those branches have been previously expanded, their data is not yet known to the model, so they wouldn't be expanded unless told to do so explicitly.   at least that is how I interpret it. @Zwornik

Comment: In the code, I pasted at the top `expandAll` does nothing. Do you know why? Well, it does but only in the code described in the first part of my previous comment.

Comment: expandAll only works on data that has already been pre-fetched.  So it will only work on branches you have expanded previously.  At least that is my understanding.  If you were using a different model that loaded all of the info upon intitialization it would work the way you expect, it's because you are using the filesystem model and the fact that it lazily fetches information.  Which by the way is a good thing. @Zwornik  if you actually expanded your full filesystem the app would likely crash

Comment: Thanks, Alexander, very helpful explanations. I am aware that `expandAll` if it worked, would potentially crash if run on a large folder. But I'm just trying to learn here and understand why most of my attempts of using PyQt fail. So I implemented `fechMore` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore before calling `expandAll` and obviously, it does nothing. Looks like it is going to be the topic of my another question here.

Comment: @Zwornik  You might be better off implementing your own FileSystemModel... Creating a custom model is a great learning experience and in the process you will become much more familiar with both python and Qt, with the added bonus of having your model work exactly the way you want it to work